# Integer type for data structure index

Tags: c++, data-types

I have implemented an append-only tree data structure as a class in C++20. Internally it uses `std::vector<Node<T>>` where `Node<T>` contains an `int parent_index` and `T payload`. A node without a parent has `parent_index = -1` as special value.

I am wondering which integer type would make the most sense here. I have good arguments for too many of them:

- `int`: It is simple to type (bad reason), easy to read and understand (just slightly better). It supports negative numbers, but not too large numbers. I know that in my application the number of nodes will be low enough, and this is not a library, so it doesn't matter.
- `size_t`: This is the index type of the underlying `std::vector`, so it might make sense to copy that. It doesn't support negative numbers, so my `parent_id` would need to become `std::optional<size_t>`, which might actually be an improvement. I don't like unsigned types because I don't want the defined overflow behavior. I just want an index.
- `ssize_t`: Doesn't have the size limitations of `int`, but also doesn't have the defined overflow from `size_t`, which I don't want.

Are there some better criteria to choose the indexing type with?

Comment: I am pretty old school, so I would probably use `int`, for exactly the reasons you mentioned: easy to type and readable (assumed I know for sure the program will never ever have to work on a <32 bit platform). The most idiomatic "modern" variant is probably `ssize_t`, but it might require to define this type by oneself on certain platforms. If you really can't decide, make a `typedef int index_t`, use `index_t` wherever you want the index, and when it becomes an issue, you can always replace the base type again.

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` would be a logical choice, since an array index *is* the difference between a pointer to the desired element and a pointer to the start of the array.  I think it's equivalent to `ssize_t`, though, unless your platform has some weird memory model.